# Updating stackview constraints results in crash: "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint"

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, autolayout, uistackview

I am attempting to update the constraints in the stack view programatically when the view changes orientation on an **iPad**.

The view by default has **20pt** to leading and trailing (in landscape) but, I want to change it to be **8pt** when it becomes portrait.

**(I am unable to add size constraint classes because the device is currently on an iPad and size classes are both wRhR.)**

At the moment I am only changing the constraints via a button click with the following:

```
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 8)
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: topLabel, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 160)

    // remove old constraints
    stackView.removeConstraints(stackView.constraints)
    stackView.addConstraints([leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, topConstraint])

    stackView.updateConstraints()
```

which results in a crash:

`The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000092520 H:|-(20)-[UIStackView:0x7fbfcbd0bf90]   (inactive, names: '|':UIView:0x7fbfcbe04150 )>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.`

[image]
[image]

Edit: This is the layout of my interface builder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note the crash message:

> When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself).

That means the `stackView` isn't a subview of the `contentView` (or vice-versa) yet.

Comment: That's odd. In interface builder though the `stackView` is inside the `contentView`. Is that not an indication that `stackView` is the subview from that point? Edited original post to show my interface builder layout

Comment: Is there a way to get it into the subview? I have not have any luck since